# Problem related to the type of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> The partial differential equation $y^{3}u_{xx}-(x^{2}-1)u_{yy}=0$ is
>
> (a) parabolic in $\{(x,y):x<0\}$,
>
> (b) hyperbolic in $\{(x,y):y>0\}$,
>
> (c) elliptic in $\Bbb R^{2}$,
>
> (d) parabolic in $\{(x,y):x>0\}$.

I have to determine which of the given options is correct. I know that a partial differential equation of the form
$$Au_{xx}+Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_{x}+Eu_{y}+F=0$$
is parabolic, hyperbolic or elliptic according as $B^{2}-4AC=0$, $>0$ or $<0$ respectively. Here, I see $B^{2}-4AC=y^{3}(x^2-1)$. From hereon, I could not progress. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the options are correct.

The discriminant $\Delta = B^2 - 4AC$ satisfies

- parabolic: $\Delta = 0$ iff $x = \pm 1$ or $y = 0$
- hyperbolic: $\Delta > 0$ iff either ($y > 0$ and $|x| > 1$) or ($y < 0$ and $|x| < 1$)
- elliptic: $\Delta < 0$ iff either ($y < 0$ and $|x| > 1$) or ($y > 0$ and $|x| < 1$)